# How to achieve european style VAT in Ubercart 3?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ubercart

I would like to implement european style VAT taxes in ubercart.

Right now, this is sort of possible except for the fact that only the sell price is saved with taxes in the db.

What I need:

- I need to be able to choose the tax on a per product basis. For example: food products usually have a VAT of 6% while most other items have a VAT of 21%. I need to select this at product creation.
- I need to be able to save both the cost price and the sell price with a tax amount (this could be a different amount)

Possible solutions:

The first problem could be solved by creating a tax taxonomy, attaching this to the product and checking for it in rules. The problem is that I don't seem to be able to do any checks on the taxonomy of a product at the tax conditions.

I don't have any ideas (or a good enough understanding of ubercart) to solve the second problem.

I know about the uc_vat module but it is not available for ubercart 3.
And there don't seem to be any modules with similar functionality on drupal.org.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: https://drupal.org/project/uc_vat

Comment: @ARUN Thanks, but like I said, I know this module exists but it is not available for ubercart 3.

Comment: it would be better for you to use the product classes.
Regards